# ERROR. Could not start Hadoop datanode daemon

Tags: hadoop

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6e2a766, pid=2084, tid=3027630960
JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
Problematic frame:
v  [libjvm.so+0x1a9766]

ERROR. Could not start Hadoop datanode daemon

Comment: Where is the log files of jre? I get the same error message 'ERROR. Could not start Hadoop datanode daemon' but i haven't problem of disk space or RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such things happens when there is zero space on the disk. Shortage of memory also can cause it, but disk is more frequent cause IMHO.